# Two input texts with only one submit allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I currently have these two input text fields with different search functions and I'm trying to make it so that only 1 search function can go through after an `onclick` -event, depending on which input field is empty.

HTML;

```
<form onsubmit="return false" id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" id="searchGroup" placeholder="Search group" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text"id="searchRoom" placeholder="Search room" autocomplete="off">                                                   
</form> 

<div id="navBtns">
    <button type="button" class="navForward" id="plus" onclick="forward();"></button>
    <button type="button" class="navBackward" id="minus" onclick="backward();"></button>                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</div>
```

This is what I've tried in JavaScript, but I can't get it to work;

```
function forward() {
    if (searchGroup.length === 0) {
        roomForward();
    } else if (searchRoom.length === 0) {
        groupForward();
    }
}

function backward() {
        if (searchGroup.length === 0) {
            roomBackward();
        } else if (searchRoom.length === 0) {
            groupBackward();
        }
    }
```

So, the idea is when text input `searchGroup` is empty, it only executes the function when `searchRoom` has some input and vice versa.

Any quick and effective ways I could solve this?

Comment: Are you declaring `searchGroup` and `searchRoom` as elements anywhere? You can't just do `id.property`, you need to get the element using the id, and do `element.property`. Additionally, you don't want the length of the element, you want the length of its value: `element.value.length`.

Comment: You need to use `searchGroup.value.length`.

Comment: @Santi `You can't just do id.property` actually you can in most browsers as all elements with an `id` are placed as properties under the `window`. Although I agree it's not very good practice

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Wow, I'm not sure how I wasn't previously aware of that. Thank you!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Just about to say the same.  And agree it's not a great feature of browers, basically ID tags pallute the global..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 'value' before the length property. So it should be 'searchGroup.value.length' for example.